# Plone 4: Get the parent of a page in a portlet template

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have something like: site/country-1/item-1/item-2/item-3

In Item 3 I have a portlet. In its template I'm trying to show the title of `Item 2` or `Item 1`. How can I do this?

`<div tal:content="python:context.Title()"></div>` gives me `Item 3`.

`<div tal:content="python:context.aq_parent"></div>` gives me `<plone.app.portlets.portlets.classic.Renderer object at 0x7fa76b97a990>`

`<div tal:content="python:view"></div>` the same: `<plone.app.portlets.portlets.classic.Renderer object at 0x7fa76b97a590>`

I need this information to implement a solution to have news items and events filtered by parent country, on any level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The acquisition chain may be different from what you expect.
To see the acquisition chain check `context.aq_chain`.

You may have good luck trying `context.aq_inner.aq_parent`.
Anyway I would use the `plone_context_state` view, i.e.: `context/@@plone_context_state/parent`.

Relevant links:

- https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/context.html
- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/master/plone/app/layout/globals/context.py#L155

Comment: context.aq_inner.aq_parent - perfect for me. I tried context.aq_inner before asking the question, but stopped trying because of error: Unauthorized: You are not allowed to access 'aq_chain' in this context

Thank you very much! :)